# selenium webdriver @findby anotation throws null pointer exception

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver

Using jar- *Selenium-server-standalone-2.35.0.jar* and *IEDriverServer64.exe*

> Browser- IE11
>   UI build on AngularJS

So when I am using `@FindBy` annotation it's throwing null pointer exception.

```
@FindBy(how= How.ID, id= "abc")
public WebElement abcdropdown;
```

And if I use like this, it seems to be working fine.

```
public By abcdropdown = By.id("abc");
```

So I created a class where I have all the id's assigned like this and then using those in the test call, in this case all the id's are in the elements class.

Please let me know what the issue is.

Answer (score 0):

When you are using page factory, you have to use PageFactory.initElements(driver, page object), otherwise it will throw null pointer exception.

Make sure that you are initiatiating the elements using PageFactory.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. It worked. One quick question- Is it possible to add the pageFactory on the class level instead of the each test level? If I use it on the class level it throws null pointer exception.

Comment: When ever you are instantiating page object, you need to use papgeFactory.initElements () to avoid null pointer exception.I will put an example here later.

Comment: The easiest way to put the pageFactory.initElement (), is to put it in constructor of page object class passing the driver object as the parameter of the constructor.